# How to separately manipulate unused space on a partition?

Tags: filesystems, partition

Is there a way to access / manipulate the space on a partition that is currently *not* used by files?

Background: Forensic tools such as `foremost` usually work on partitions, so when I use it on a partition that is currently in use, it will identify all the files that are currently on it. But I want to use it to only analyse the free space, e.g. to verify that no recoverable data remains in that free space.

Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Since it works with partitions and images directly, why don't you just run it with a partition as an argument?

Comment: In this case you could create temporarily partitions for the unpartitioned space.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I would like to avoid converting the free space into a partition, then having to add it to the original partition again afterwards.

Comment: Open the entire disk directly then. There are no other options.